# KrakenD - ERROR parsing the configuration file: loading flexible-config settings

Tags: docker, configuration, krakend

I'm trying to use krakend's flexible configuration, but there's no way to get it started in a simple way

> ERROR parsing the configuration file: loading flexible-config settings:
> 2022-07-19T08:48:21.279006680Z  - "config/settings/dev": open "config/settings/dev": no such file or directory

I'm just trying to load a configuration file with a simple variable, to test the gateway.
but I'm not assigning that variable anywhere for now

**dev/env.json**

```
{
  "port": 8080
}
```

I show you my configuration of **docker-compose.yaml**

```
shared-gateway:
    build:
      context: ${PWD}/.docker/krakend
    container_name: 'shared-gateway'
    restart: "unless-stopped"
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/.docker/krakend/:/etc/krakend/
    ports:
      - "9191:8080"
    networks:
      - network-gateway
    environment:
      - FC_ENABLE=1
      - FC_SETTINGS="config/settings/dev"
    command: ['run',  '-c', '/etc/krakend/krakend.json']
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM devopsfaith/krakend:2.0.5
COPY krakend.json /etc/krakend/krakend.json
```

I show you my directory tree

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── config
│   ├── partials
│   ├── settings
│   │   ├── dev
│   │   │   └── env.json
│   │   └── prod
│   └── templates
└── krakend.json
```

When I start the container, it tells me that it can't find the directory

> ERROR parsing the configuration file: loading flexible-config settings:
> 2022-07-19T09:25:12.390870759Z  - "config/settings/dev": open "config/settings/dev": no such file or directory

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong or have an example of how to use krakend's [flexible-configuration](https://www.krakend.io/docs/configuration/flexible-config/) with docker?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you either don't copy the "config" directory into directory "/etc/krakend/" in your docker image or mount it ("config") from outside in your docker compose file. I believe the the image work directory is at "/etc/krakend", so make sure you make your config folder available under that directory, before you start "run" command

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `config` folder is not present in your Docker image. I would suggest using this `Dockerfile` example that uses Flexible Configuration that does exactly what you want:

https://www.krakend.io/docs/deploying/docker/